# Using split function without split() string method. Almost

Tags: python, for-loop, split

I'm trying to replicate the .split() string method. It works well but it doesn't include the last word.

```
def stringSplitter(string):
    words = []
    current_word = ""
    for x in range(len(string)): #problem is here
        if string[x] == " ":
            words.append(current_word)
            current_word = ""
        else:
            current_word += string[x]
    return words
```

Test 1: When sentence=I like to ride my bicycle, my code incorrectly outputs:

```
['I', 'like', 'to', 'ride', 'my']
```

The result I want is:

```
['I', 'like', 'to', 'ride', 'my', 'bicycle']
```

Comment: If you are using indexing in your python for loop, you're usually doing something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `words.append(current_word)` just before returning from the function. That's your "lost" word. Also, there is no need to use either `range` or any indexing. `for x in string:` iterates directly over the characters.

Comment: Thank you! Finally, so this is what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2):

Note this could be implemented more succinctly using a generator function - if you didn't mind deviating from the "real" `str.split()` function implementation a little bit:

```
>>> def split(string, delimiter=' '):
    current_word = ''
    for char in string:
        if char == delimiter:
            yield current_word
            current_word = ''
        else:
            current_word += char
    yield current_word


>>> list(split('I like to ride my bicycle'))
['I', 'like', 'to', 'ride', 'my', 'bicycle']
>>>
```

You could even modify it to allow returning the delimiter as well:

```
>>> def split(string, delimiter=' ', save_delimiter=False):
    current_word = ''
    for char in string:
        if char == delimiter:
            yield current_word
            if save_delimiter:
                yield char
            current_word = ''
        else:
            current_word += char
    yield current_word


>>> list(split('I like to ride my bicycle', save_delimiter=True))
['I', ' ', 'like', ' ', 'to', ' ', 'ride', ' ', 'my', ' ', 'bicycle']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it with the help of the first answer by @DYZ. Thank you! Apparently, I was skipping the last word because I need to add (below) before the return.

```
words.append(current_word)
```

My Code:

```
def stringSplitter(string):
    words = []
    current_word = ""
    for char in string:
        if char == " ":
            words.append(current_word)
            current_word = ""
        else:
            current_word += char
    words.append(current_word)        
    return words
```